# Getting mysqlnd into PHP 5.4... With or around EasyApache

Tags: php

I'm likely not thinking of some information that may be relevant, but here's pretty much what I've been trying to sort out.

I (unfortunately) am in charge of a server infested with cPanel. For various reasons I've been attempting to get the mysqlnd driver compiled into PHP. The current setup on the server is WHM/cPanel, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4, and MySQL 5.1 on centos 5.8 x64.

As I understand it I should be able to do this through EasyApache. At least according to this: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/CustomConfigureFlags

However trying to add the extra flags for PHP results in these complaints.

```
./configure: line 61087: test: mysqlnd: binary operator expected
./configure: line 61091: test: mysqlnd: binary operator expected
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under mysqlnd .
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
```

The options I tried to use are:

```
--with-mysql=mysqlnd 
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd 
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

I get the feeling I'm overlooking something fairly obvious. If the most sane solution is to dodge EasyApache I don't really have a problem with that.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `--with-mysqli` is sufficient to build PHP with mysqlnd. The error message seems to suggest that the MySQL client library is not bundled, so you need to install it, both binary and header files. If the MySQL client library is installed but the configure script can't find it pass the path to the headers and library to the configure script.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out it was indeed just a matter of --with-mysqli.